# Is it possible to derive a parser for an arbitrary type that parses the corresponding Debug format?

Tags: parsing, rust

In Haskell, it is possible, as a language feature, to [derive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/derive.html) a parser from a string to an arbitrary datatype: that's called the [`Read` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html). Is it possible to do so in Rust? That is, given an arbitrary `enum` such as:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Foo {
    A { x: u32, s: String },
    B { v: Vec<u8> },
}
```

and, given that Rust includes the `Debug` trait as a language feature that serializes an arbitrary datatype, is it possible to also automatically generate its corresponding `Parse` trait?

In other words, is there a default Rust feature that allows me to derive a `parse(&str) -> Foo` function such that, for any string `s` either `parse(&s) == None` or `format!("{:?}", parse(&s).unwrap()) == s`?

Comment: serde is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: You may be interested in [RON](https://github.com/ron-rs/ron), a data format that is something of a middle ground between JSON and what `Debug` outputs, and does support deserialization through serde.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377141/why-was-this-specific-question-about-rust-generics-put-on-hold)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such feature. `Debug` is intended for human/programmer consumption, not for machines.

There's no guarantee that the `Debug` output is even in a parseable format or that it contains the complete data of a type.

I recommend using [Serde](https://serde.rs/) instead, paired with an existing defined serialization format of your choice.

If you wanted to, you could define your *own* `derive` attributes that implement `Debug` and `FromStr` by calling into Serde.